# gearshift problem on Polo 1.6 2007 econoline

Tags: ford

My gears seems to have moved a position to the right. Reverse sutsd where 1st should sit 3rd where 5th should be and 5 th no where to be found as I'm out of space by then. Also note we changed the clutch and pressure plates and also the innet right cv. Help please

Comment: Can you clarify what vehcile this is? A Polo (VW) or a Ford Econoline?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds to me like a gear linkage problem - depending on the vehile you've either got a mechanical linkage or a set of cables to move the gears based on where you move the stick, and I suspect the one that controls side-to-side movement is broken or misaligned.

I've seen both problems before, on different vehicles - once where a mechanical linkage became misaligned and so couldn't get all the gears, and once where a bowden cable snapped and prevented fore-and-aft movement...